# Single consumer and single producer lock-free circular buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, circular-list, lock-free

I'm pretty new to multithreading. The code below is a simple implementation of a single consumer/single producer circular buffer that does not use any locking, that I wrote for fun.

The question is, will this kind of container work in actual real world situation or would it crash miserably because of some data race that I have not noticed?

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <random>


template<typename T, int S=5>
class CircularBuffer{
public:
  CircularBuffer():start(0),end(0){
  }
  bool AddElement(std::unique_ptr<T> && obj,bool block=true){

    int end_idx=end.load();
    if(block)
      while(end_idx+1==start.load());//Busy wait until there is place
    else if(end_idx+1==start.load())
      return false;

    buffer[end_idx++]=std::move(obj);
    if(end_idx==buffer.size())
      end.store(0);
    else
      end.store(end_idx); 
    return true;
  }
  std::unique_ptr<T> GetElement(bool block=true){
      int start_idx=start.load();
      if(block)
        while(end.load()==start_idx);
      else if(end.load()==start_idx)
        return std::unique_ptr<T>();

      auto ret_obj=std::move(buffer[start_idx]);
      start_idx++;
      if(start_idx==buffer.size())
    start.store(0);
      else
    start.store(start_idx);
      return ret_obj;      
  }

private:  
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<T>,S+1> buffer;
  std::atomic<int> start;
  std::atomic<int> end;

};

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0,500);

void Producer(CircularBuffer<int> * buffer){

  int i=0;
  while(i<20){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(dis(gen)));
    auto val=dis(gen);
    std::cout << "Adding " << val <<std::endl;
    buffer->AddElement(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(val)));
    i++;
  }
}
void Consumer(CircularBuffer<int> * buffer){

  int i=0;
  while(i<20){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(dis(gen)));
    std::cout << "Got " << *buffer->GetElement() << std::endl;
    i++;
  }

}

int main(){

  CircularBuffer<int> buffer;

  std::thread t[2];
  t[0]=std::thread(Producer,&buffer);
  t[1]=std::thread(Consumer,&buffer);

  t[0].join();
  t[1].join();
}
```

Comment: This is actually off-topic cause you ask review of the actual working of your code. We do review on your code as in improve your code writing, sometimes a faster or better solution. For your question, the best is to write some tests and test your code by them.

Comment: @chillworld On the other hand, their question implies another question which is "how can I improve my code to be sure that it's thread-safe". A little reformulation would make the question on-topic :)

Answer (score 7):

A few notes, mostly unrelated to the actual lock-free nature of the code:

1. Some of your names are a lot less meaningful than I'd like. A prime example is your template parameter `S` in: `template<typename T, int S=5>`. This should probably be renamed to something like `Size` instead. Although not quite as problematic, I'd say your `dis` and `gen` have pretty much the same problem as well. (Note that although `T` as the type parameter is just as short, it's so common I'd accept it, much like I'd accept `i` as the index for a loop).
2. Although some people avoid them, I'd at least *consider* using something like `size_t` for the types of `CircularBuffer::begin` and `CircularBuffer::end`. It appears that neither should ever be negative.
3. You might want to consider using `std::atomic_int` (or `std::atomic_uint`) instead of `std::atomic<int>`. It's unlikely to make *much* difference, but does give the library design a little extra chance for optimization (i.e., `atomic_int` might just be a typedef for `atomic<int>`, but could be a separate type instead, if the library designer sees an advantage in doing so).
4. It may just be a side-effect of some strange tab expansion (or something similar) but at least as posted, your indentation is pretty strange in a few places. For one obvious example:

   ```
     if(start_idx==buffer.size())
   start.store(0);
     else
   start.store(start_idx);
   ```
5. I'd have to do some looking to be *absolutely* certain, but I *believe* your use of a global for the random number generator causes a data race that leads to undefined behavior. Specifically, a pseudo-random number generator has an internal state that's modified when you obtain a random number from it. Doing that modification simultaneously from two or more threads gives undefined behavior.
6. This sequence:

   ```
     start_idx++;
     if(start_idx==buffer.size())
   start.store(0);
     else
   start.store(start_idx);
   ```

Looks to me like it's subject to race conditions. For example, let's assume `start_idx` starts out equal to `buffer_size-1`, then we execute the code above from two threads:

```
thread A: start_idx++;  
thread B: start_idx++;

thread A: if (start_idx == buffer.size())
thread B: if (start_idx == buffer.size())
```

Both if statements return false--`start_idx` is now one *greater* than `buffer.size()`. We then store `start_idx` into `start`.

The next time the function is called, it attempts to use:

```
auto ret_obj=std::move(buffer[start_idx]);
```

...and `start_idx` indexes past the end of `buffer`, giving undefined behavior.

Limiting to single-producer, single-consumer *may* be enough to prevent this problem from manifesting, but 1) I find that an essentially useless model, and 2) I'm not at all sure it's sufficient even then.

Although it may sound defeatist, let me give one little bit of advice: when you first do multithreaded programming, you're a lot better off sticking to using locks, mutexes, and so on. Getting just that much right will keep you busy for quite a while.

(Only) once you've gotten to the point that it's easy to handle that, *then* start to move on to working at lock-free programming (but be aware that it's an area where even the very best, brightest and most experienced *still* get things wrong quite frequently.

Comment: +10 (If I could) on the using locks comment. People new to threading jump trying a lock free implementation (probably because its cool). But lock free code is extremely hard to get correct and the chance of subtle bugs is huge. Write the versions with locks first. Prove it is correct (and not fast enough) before trying  a lock free version.

Comment: @LokiAstari: ...and then live with the fact that although the lock-free version guarantees forward progress (assuming you've done it correctly), it may not be any faster than the version that uses locking (and could even be slower). Yes, there's a good chance it'll be faster, but certainly no guarantee.